# How to check if external microphone is being used via ADB

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to check through ADB whether or not the external wired headset mic is used or not.  This mic is automatically detected when I plug in the wired headset, but for external scripting purposes, it would be very helpful to detect this action.

I couldn't find an intent for the microphone, but looked up the headset intent here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

I tried this broadcast intent for detecting the headset alone:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG
```

which gets this response whether or not a wired headset is actually plugged in:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here.  I can't even detect if the headset is plugged in, much less if the external microphone is being used.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Audio manager reference points to some extra values: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG  
    state - 0 for unplugged, 1 for plugged.
    name - Headset type, human readable string
    microphone - 1 if headset has a microphone, 0 otherwise
Maybe I have to access these somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this method works on my device:

Run the command

`adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts | grep microphone`

which should produce something like:

```
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]
extras: Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
  Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]
```

The last line is inside the sticky broadcasts section of the dump, the broadcasts that remain the same until changed.

So if we take the last line using `tail` and dissect it, it contains the current state of the headset:

`adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts | grep microphone | tail -n 1`

output:

`Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]`

The `state` integer refers to whether something is plugged into the headphone jack, regardless of it contains a microphone. 0 for unplugged and 1 for plugged in.

The `microphone` integer refers to if the headset that was last plugged in also included a microphone. 0 for no, 1 for yes.

## Scenarios

If a normal pair of headphones is currently plugged in, the output will be:

`Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=0}]`

---

If a headset with a microphone is currently plugged in, the output will be:

`Bundle[{name=h2w, state=1, microphone=1}]`

---

If nothing is plugged in, the output is either:

`Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=0}]`

or

`Bundle[{name=h2w, state=0, microphone=1}]`

Comment: This is great, thanks!  I verified the same outputs in the same use cases you mention.  This is can for sure be used to determined if the external headset has a mic or not.  One issue I noticed (at least on my phone) that after a period of no headset plugging activity, there were no more broadcast messages for the headset action.  So this works mainly when a "recent" event has occurred?

Comment: I don't get any output from this command. Do you think that might mean the microphone is not working at all? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180450/how-to-determine-which-application-is-blocking-microphone-usage